# Print out key/value pairs using HTML and Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a key/value pair object in Typescript:

```
myFields: { [key: string]: string } = {};
```

I'm trying to create a grid that lists each key next to their value e.g.

```
name: John
lastname: Smith
age: 40
```

I know how to make the grid, but I'm not sure how to get each key name and value.

```
    <div *ngIf="myFields" class="fields-grid-container">
        <div *ngFor="let field of myFields" class="fields-grid-item">
            {{field}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I currently have but nothing displays. What's the proper way to print a key/value pair array in html? Would it be better to create a string array and build each string element as the key + value and use that instead?

Comment: NgForOf expects iterator give it result of object.entries or prepare the  object in other manner beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pipe KeyValuePipe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someObject | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}: {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xs6zn?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Note this is valid from Angular 6.1 and later. See https://blog.angular.io/angular-v6-1-now-available-typescript-2-9-scroll-positioning-and-more-9f1c03007bb6